# Run python script using node js error no 22

Tags: javascript, node.js, python-3.x, express

I'm using node.js to run a python script through the web browser. below is the ScriptRunner.js code.

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var path = require('path');
exports.runScript = function() {
   var options = {
       scriptPath: 'D:\L4Project\working code\finalproject\routes'
   };
PythonShell.run('sensitive2.py',options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('results: %j', results);
});
}
```

when I run the script in browser it returns error message like below.

```
D:\L4Project\working code\finalproject\routes\scriptRunner.js:10
      if (err) throw err;
               ^

outes\sensitive2.py': [Errno 22] Invalid argumentg codeinalproject at PythonShell.parseError (D:\L4Project\working code\finalproject\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:191:17)
    at terminateIfNeeded (D:\L4Project\working code\finalproject\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:98:28)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\L4Project\working code\finalproject\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:89:9)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
```

I have googles lot and nothing worked. Can Somebody help me to solve the problem?

Comment: are you setting your python path ?

Comment: yes.I can run python script in python idle.no errors